# Repair File System After changing the partition structure

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, mbr

I have dual booted linux centOs with windows. Now I changed the partition structure of linux with a partedMagic live CD. Since I have used the EasyBcd to make the boot menu on windows, I can still boot Windows, but not linux. I think now I have to repair partitions specifying the system what id / partition, what is /boot partition and what is swap.

For the ease of understanding I'm attaching before and after partition structure. 
Before : 
[image]

After : [image]

What must I do now for repair the file system. What are the steps I must follow roughly?

Comment: If you now get any particular errors when trying to boot Linux, it would be worth adding those details to the question.

Comment: Previously system is booted from linux grub. Knowing that the grub is going to currupt, I installed easyBCD to boot at-least windows after the partition change. But the problem is easyBCD has an issue with CentOs. So the error I get is related with that issue. It has no clear answer yet. So What I want now is to establish grub again  to load both linux and windows.

Comment: I overwrote the MBR with Grub. Then Disabled the easyBCD boot menu. I was not able to boot from linux since my partitions are changed. So I edit the partition label by pressing 'e' on the grub boot menu item of centOs to the correct one and was able to successfully enter in to the centOs system. Then I edit the grub.conf permanently to the correct boot partitions and now everything is OK. Thanks.